# Tree map- colorAxis Behaving Differently

Tags: jquery, highcharts, treemap

Following are the JS files used.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost-canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Below is the code to generate a Trea Map graph,

```
 var chartId = _containerId;// "containergraph_" + loop;
        Highcharts.chart(chartId,
                     {
                         chart: {
                             useHTML: true,
                             backgroundColor: {
                                 linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                                 stops: [
                                     [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                                     [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                                 ]
                             },

                             borderWidth: 2,
                             plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
                             plotShadow: true,
                             plotBorderWidth: 1, marginBottom: 20,
                             marginTop: 100,
                             events: {
                                 load: function () {
                                     this.credits.element.onclick = function () {
                                         window.open(
                                           '/about',
                                           '_blank'
                                         );
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         title: {
                             text: Title,
                             y: 50,
                             verticalAlign: 'top',


                         },

                         lang: {
                             some_key: 'Click to view All Sectors',
                             some_key2: 'All Sector',
                             some_key3: 'Back',

                         },
                         exporting: {
                             buttons: {
                                 exportButton: {
                                     align: 'left',
                                     x: 40
                                 },
                                 contextButton: {
                                     enabled: false
                                 },

                                 customButton: {
                                     text: 'Click to view All Sectors',
                                     _titleKey: 'some_key',
                                     onclick: function () {


                                         if (lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode.length !== lss_fgss_lms_fgms_AggregationLevel) {
                                             if (_classification_1 == 'HS') {
                                                 lss_fgss_lms_fgms_AggregationLevel = lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode.length + 2;

                                             }
                                             if (_classification_1 == 'ST') {
                                                 lss_fgss_lms_fgms_AggregationLevel = lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode.length + 1;
                                             }
                                         };

                                         whattoclick('btn_showAll_containergraph', TabIndex.toString(), lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode, $("#PartnersCountries").select2('data')[TabIndex].id);

                                     },
                                     align: 'left',
                                     x: 0,
                                     theme: {
                                         fill: '#8AC700',
                                         'stroke-width': 1,
                                         stroke: '#f2f2f2',
                                         r: 0,
                                         states: {
                                             hover: {
                                                 fill: '#bada55'
                                             },
                                             select: {
                                                 stroke: '#039',
                                                 fill: '#bada55'
                                             }
                                         }
                                     },
                                     style: {
                                         color: '#FFFFFF',
                                         fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                         fontSize: '14px',
                                     }
                                 },

                                 backButton: {
                                     align: 'left',
                                     x: 180,
                                     theme: {
                                         fill: '#8AC700',
                                         'stroke-width': 1,
                                         stroke: '#f2f2f2',
                                         r: 0,
                                         states: {
                                             hover: {
                                                 fill: '#bada55'
                                             },
                                             select: {
                                                 stroke: '#039',
                                                 fill: '#bada55'
                                             }
                                         }
                                     },
                                     enabled: lssbackstatus,
                                     text: 'Return to Parent(Top Sectors)',
                                     _titleKey: 'some_key3',
                                     onclick: function () {

                                         ShowParentGraph_New(TabIndex.toString(), lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode, $("#PartnersCountries").select2('data')[TabIndex].id);

                                     }
                                 },

                                 printButton: {
                                     text: 'Print',
                                     _titleKey: 'printChart',
                                     onclick: function () {
                                         this.print();
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         credits:
                       {
                           enabled: true,
                           text: 'Copyright © 2017 East-West.World, All Right Reserved'
                       },
                         legend: {
                             enabled: false
                         },
                        /* colorAxis: {


                             dataClasses: [
                                   { to: 0.99, color: 'pink', name: '<1' },
                                   { from: 1.00, to: 5.99, color: '#92D050', name: '1.00 - 5.99' },

                                   { from: 6.00, to: 10.99, color: '#A9D18D', name: '6.00 to 10.99' },
                                   { from: 11.00, to: 15.99, color: '#C5E0B2', name: '11.00 to 15.99' },

                                   { from: 16.00, to: 20.99, color: '#FFFF00', name: '16.00 to 20.99' },
                                   { from: 21.00, to: 25.99, color: '#FFDA65', name: '21.00 to 25.99' },

                                   { from: 26.00, to: 30.99, color: '#FF6600', name: '26.00 to 30.99' },
                                   { from: 31.00, to: 35.99, color: '#FF3300', name: '31.00 to 35.99' },

                                   { from: 40.00, color: '#FF0000', name: '>40.00' },
                             ]
                         },*/
                         colorAxis: {
                             minColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                             maxColor: '#FFFFFF',
                         },
                         tooltip: {
                             // backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
                             width: '100px',
                             shared: true,
                             useHTML: true,
                             formatter: function () {

                                 if (typeof this.point.NewField === 'undefined') {
                                     alert("undefined variable");
                                     _newfield = "";
                                 }
                                 else {
                                     _newfield = this.point.NewField.substring(0, 90) + "...";
                                 }
                                 return '<table id="TooltipGraphs" width="400px" class="table-4 display row-border order-column preview-table text-center" border="1">' +
                              '<tr class="TooltipHeading"><td colspan="3">' + _newfield + '</td><td>Change</td></tr>' +
                              '<tr><td>Heading</td><td>' + ToYear + '</td><td>' + FromYear + '</td><td>' + ToYear + '-' + FromYear + '</td></tr>' +
                              '<tr class=""><td colspan="1">' + "Trade Value" + '</td><td>$' + UpdateComma(this.point.tradevalueTo) + '</td><td>' + UpdateComma(this.point.tradevalueFrom) + '</td><td>' + UpdateComma(this.point.tradevalueTo - this.point.tradevalueFrom) + '</td></tr>' +

                              '<tr class="MarketShareTr"><td colspan="1">' + "Market Share" + '</td><td><b>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketShareEnd) + '%</b></td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketShareStart) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketShareEnd - this.point.MarketShareStart) + '%</td></tr>' +
                              '<tr class="ContributionTr"><td colspan="1">' + "Contribution" + '</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.ContributionEnd) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.ContributionStart) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.ContributionEnd - this.point.ContributionStart) + '%</td></tr>' +
                               '<tr class="SectorShareTr"><td colspan="1">' + "Sector Share" + '</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.SectorEnd) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.SectorStart) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.SectorEnd - this.point.SectorStart) + '%</td></tr>' +
                              '<tr class="MarketSpecializationTr"><td colspan="1">' + "Market Specialization" + '</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketSpecializationEnd) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketSpecializationStart) + '%</td><td>' + RoundTo2DeciamlPalce(this.point.MarketSpecializationEnd - this.point.MarketSpecializationStart) + '%</td></tr>' +
                              '</table>';
                             }
                              ,
                             positioner: function () {
                                 return { x: 0, y: 80 };
                             }
                         },
                         series: [{
                             type: 'treemap',
                             layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
                             data: _newJsonData,
                             name: "Heat Map",
                             showInLegend: false,

                         }],

                         plotOptions: {
                             treemap: {
                             minPointLength: 3,
                             PixelPointWidth: 30
                         },
                             series: {
                                 showInLegend: true,
                                 cursor: 'pointer',
                                 point: {
                                     events: {
                                         click: function () {
                                             if (_classification_1 == "HS" && this.options.name.split("<br/>")[0].length == 6) {
                                                 // jAlert('Maximum Aggregation level Reached.', "HS Sectors");
                                                 return false;
                                             }
                                             if (_classification_1 != "HS" && this.options.name.split("<br/>")[0].length == 5) {
                                                 //jAlert('Maximum Aggregation level Reached.', "SITC Sectors");
                                                 return false;
                                             }

                                             lssbackstatus = true;
                                             lss_fgss_lms_fgms_CommodityCode = this.options.name.split("<br/>")[0];
                                             LMS_Child_Graph(this.options.name.split("<br/>")[0], (TabIndex))
                                             return false;

                                         },
                                         legendItemClick: function () {
                                             var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                                             if (!confirm('The series is currently ' +
                                                          visibility + '. Do you want to change that?')) {
                                                 return false;
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }



                     });
```

The graph [coloraxis] is behaving differently, on the Graph has treemap with Blue Color, when you expand any of the tree element the next graph is also on blue color, When I click Back to Parent, The graph colors behaves as expected, but when I again traverse through the graph it's color changes from Shades of Green to Blue.

You can have a look what I mean through this gif created. [Here](http://g.recordit.co/znzuaJppNE.gif) .

Following the link for the actual page. [Actual Page](http://staging.east-west.world/data).

**ColorAxis Defined**

```
 colorAxis: {
                             minColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                             maxColor: '#FFFFFF',
                         },
```

Following is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/m0wzdffo/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing colorValue in the required input JSON,

Correct Structure

```
 [{
  "MarketShareStart": 2.03,
  "MarketShareEnd": 1.71,
  "NewField": "040900-Honey; natural",
  "value": 1.71,
  "startvalue": 2.03,
  "tradevalueFrom": 20718254,
  "tradevalueTo": 17075985,
  "colorValue": 0, // This is the key I was missing
  "name": "040900<br>(1.71)",
  "ContributionStart": 0.01,
  "ContributionEnd": 0.02,
  "SectorStart": 0.02,
  "SectorEnd": 0.02,
  "MarketSpecializationStart": 0.32,
  "MarketSpecializationEnd": 0.28
}]
```

Working fiddle below.
https://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/d8wb73dw/